# SQlite raw query for insert stement

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need help how to implement rawquery in sqlite. I need to insert a record in to specific row in table. I searched and found that I can achieve this using raw query. I am new to sqlite and don't know how to implement raw query. I got syntax error.

Here is my code

```
public void insert (String potision, String total, String curent)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO  "+Table_Name2+" VALUES(?,?) WHERE ID = ? ", new String[] {total,curent,potision});
}
```

Here is my syntax error:

> SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO  item_counts_2 VALUES(?,?) WHERE ID = ?

Help will be appreciated

Comment: This happens when you don't know the difference between a SQL **query** and a SQL **command**. And `WHERE` is not used in **INSERT**s. You maybe want to execute an **UPDATE** or a **REPLACE**, instead.

Comment: Erase `WHERE ID = ? ` and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a `syntax error` because you added a `where` clause to an insert.

When you execute an `insert`, you are adding a row to the database. There is no sense in specifying a row.

If you were updating a row, then, the `where` clause would be fine, because you have to tell him what row to update.

Also when deleting rows, the `where` clause is widely used, so that you don't erase the whole table.

Insert: [official docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

Update: [official docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html)

Delete: [official docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html)

Note that the docs refer to SQLite, since you are using Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **update** query with **ContentValues** to update specific row data in your DB like this

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(COLUMN_1, value1);
values.put(COLUMN_2, value2);
return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(idValue) });
```

Hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `where` clause with `insert` query.

If you are inserting a new row to database then `where` clause is redundant, remove it and it will work fine.

OR,

If you want to update value already exist in database, use `update` query instead of `insert`,
for more information visit [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).